# Fragments - The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, android-fragments, surfaceview

I am getting this error. I tried many solutions but I coudn't solve this. Help me! I need to add the surface view and the button to the activity using fragments.

CamActivity.java:

```
public class CamActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cam);
        
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
        
        if(fragment == null) {
            fragment = new CamFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
            .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

CamFragment.java:

```
public class CamFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "CamFragment";
    
    private Camera mCamera;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, parent);
    
    Button capturePic = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.img_capture);
    capturePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });
    
    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)v.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    return v;
}

}
```

Error:

```
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pack.camdictionary/com.pack.camdictionary.CamActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1728)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1747)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3814)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:2007)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1902)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1859)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1839)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1166)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3837)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1701)
04-18 13:24:12.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6321):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: when the exception occurred. On `capturePic`  click or before it.

Comment: where should i call getParent?? @maddy before it

Comment: post your `activity_cam` xml file

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Try to replace

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, parent);
```

With

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, parent, false);
```

or

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, null);
```

Comment: Try to avoid passing null as parent, use the first option he mentioned

Comment: @sudocoder To answer your why?. Parent is the root view of the hierarchy you are inflating the resource to attach to,LayoutInflater will automatically attempt to attach the inflated view to the supplied root. However, the framework has a check in place that if you pass null for the root it bypasses this attempt to avoid ur app to crash.Parent is necessary in order to evaluate the LayoutParams declared in the root element of the XML being inflated. Passing nothing here is telling the framework u dont know the parent view of the inflated xml.

Comment: nice explanation  https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/

Answer (score 8):

This question had already been answered but still I would like to add the reason for adding **false** as the third parameter.

> The inflate() method takes three arguments:
>
> - The resource ID of the layout you want to inflate.
> - The ViewGroup to be the parent of the inflated layout. Passing the container is important in order for the system to apply layout parameters to the root view of the inflated layout, specified by the parent view in which it's going.
> - A boolean indicating whether the inflated layout should be attached to the ViewGroup (the second parameter) during inflation. (In this case, this is false because the system is already inserting the inflated layout into the container—passing true would create a redundant view group in the final layout.)

Source:  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I was doing the `setTransition()` during the `FragmentTransaction`. Below code worked for me:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        if(this::rootView.isInitialized){
            if(rootView.getParent() != null){
                (rootView.getParent() as ViewGroup).endViewTransition(rootView)
            }
            return this.rootView

        }

        ...

}
```

This probably happens when you repeatedly switch between fragments, that the view does not get time to really detach from the parent due to the ongoing transition.

Comment: Yes I can confirm that. In my specific case, some of my fragments have heavy and complex UI such as showing a Google `MapView` and user may frequently navigate between such fragments. Because re-creating their view entirely is cumbersome each time, I am doing view caching (retaining instance of the view in Fragment and returning it in `onCreateView`). But because of transition animations between 2 such fragments, both views co-exist briefly and if user navigates back quickly enough, it will crash. So calling `endViewTransition` is the solution. Thanks a lot and +1 well deserved.

Comment: Also, on a side note and strangely enough, my issue is currently concerning exclusively HUAWEI devices running Android 9. But this issue could be reproduced on a Nexus 5 and other unrelated devices. Why, I don't know... could there be an animation implementation issue proper to EMUI OS / Huawei to make it _that_ easy to happen so frequently ?

Comment: this answer is golden

Comment: wanted to try this, but seems like there's no isInitialized property for my rootView?

Answer (score 5):

I am using API 26.0.2 and in my case, the crash was happening because of custom animations set for my fragments. Commenting out the call to set the custom animation, fixed the issue.

fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                android.R.anim.fade_out);

Comment: bundle of thanks for commenting this. I opened this link but missed your answer. it took 3 days to debug this. I could have spent more days if didn't see your answer.

Comment: did you find any way to make this work with setCustomAnimations.?

Comment: @QadirHussain Sorry Hussain I didn't try.

Answer (score 2):

I also met this problem, and this is my solution. it's very easy

```
View v;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container);
    } else {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.removeView(v);
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

Hope to be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

Specify `Id` for parent and child element, especially for custom views, in `xml` file may solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your reference. It seems to be an issue in the Android SDK.

I have the same situation like @Satheesh had with the SDK version: 27.0.2 and trying to remove the setCustomAnimation seems works. But to remove the setCustomAnimations requires lots of change to make for me, I'd prefer to keep the custom animation. What I have done is to upgrade the SDK to the latest version which is 27.1.1 for now. And it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Might be Helpfull

```
           View customView1;
           inflater= (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           customView1= inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_custom_alert_window, null);     
           try {
                if(customView2.getParent()!=null)
                    ((ViewGroup)customView2.getParent()).removeView(customView2);
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had navigation in my code and this error was shown when I clicked back button from one of the fragments. It solved when in the nav_graph I put **popUpTo** in related **action**s. Some **action**s were done but didn't popup anything.

Answer (score 0):

So I had a case in which my fragment consisted of nested sub-fragments (Bottom Navigation).
Let's say I have Fragment A (which contains sub fragments) and another basic Fragment B. So while navigating from A to B, when I pressed back button, I was facing this error - *The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first*.

And I found out that the reason was in the error statement only. So in `OnDestroyView` of Fragment A, I did the following -

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    (view?.parent as? ViewGroup)?.removeAllViews()
    super.onDestroyView()
}
```

And it worked like charm.

Answer (score -1):

Error by this line:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, parent);
```

Try to replace with:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, null);
```

Answer (score -18):

try this.

```
 ((CamActivity)getActivity()).finish();
```