# Why does .addView throw this parent/child exception?

Tags: java, android, layout, android-studio

Hello!
I'm trying to create dynamic TextViews inside a LinearLayout within my main activity. The program is (supposed to be) pushing out TextView's from `resultrow` XML to `activity_fivethreeone` XML as required.
The line `parentLayout.addView(textView);` is throwing this error;

```
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I've tried answers from similar questions but getting no wins.
[Fragments - The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149981/fragments-the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview)
[Call removeView() on the child's parent first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526874/call-removeview-on-the-childs-parent-first)

class:

```
try {
    LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linLayout);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view;
    for(int counter=0;counter<=theWeeksList.size();counter++){
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.resultrow, parentLayout, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.resultRow);
        textView.setText(theWeeksList.get(counter));
        parentLayout.addView(textView);
    }
}
```

I was trying to use `removeView()` but couldn't get it to stick.
Any help will be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: hey no fair!!! I answered first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textView` has already as parent `view`, as matter  of fact you are able to look for it with findViewById successfully. So this line:

```
parentLayout.addView(textView);
```

is causing the exception. You probably want to add `view` to `parentLayout`

```
parentLayout.addView(view);
```

since it has been just created, it has no parent and can be added as child

Comment: Thank you!! I've been pulling my hair out since 4pm (it's about to hit midnight here).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add an `EditText` that already belongs to an existing `ViewGroup`.

Remove the line

```
parentLayout.addView(textView);
```

from your code. You don't need to do that. Replace it with

```
parentLayout.addView(view);
```

Comment: Much appreciated! I love/hate when it's something so small!

Comment: @jackEarlyDays: hey, sorry for replying so late ... no problem, we are all here to help each other. By the way, I answered first. I think its only fair that my answer should be marked correct :)