# Dynamically view inflation error

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating view via XML.

But after adding view it is throwing error -

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

I am using below code -

```
LinearLayout main = new LinearLayout(mContext);
main.setId(R.id.main);
main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
main.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

LinearLayout sub1 = new LinearLayout(mContext);
sub1.setId(R.id.sub1);
sub1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout_662 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
sub1.setLayoutParams(layout_662);


LinearLayout sub2 = new LinearLayout(mContext);
sub2.setId(R.id.sub2);
sub2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout_943 = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
sub2.setLayoutParams(layout_943);

for(int i=0;i<=4);i++) {

    sub1.addView(imageView[i]);
    main.addView(sub1);

    sub2.addView(imageView1[i]);
    main.addView(sub2);
}
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: R u having a view in xml'

Comment: You can see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29167798/why-does-addview-throw-this-parent-child-exception?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29167798/why-does-addview-throw-this-parent-child-exception?rq=1)

Comment: The error log clearly says the resolution to your problem

Answer (score 1):

Change your for statement this way:

```
    main.addView(sub1);
    main.addView(sub2);

    for(int i=0;i<=4);i++) {

        sub1.addView(imageView[i]);

        sub2.addView(imageView1[i]);
    }
```

You have to add sub1 and sub2 only once.

Comment: You're right, but if you look better at the code, they are two different arrays of images. So every image belongs to one only parent. imageview[] and imageview1(ONE)[]

Comment: Well, probably it depends on your ImageViews' layout params...maybe you should check them. You could show the code where you create them

Comment: By the way, from your code it seems that main view is not attached to any view...why don't you build your layout via xml?

Answer (score 0):

You've got

```
main.addView(sub1);
```

inside a for-loop. So on the second loop, it's already added to the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like below.

```
 for(int i=0;i<=4);i++) {
        sub1.addView(imageView[i]);
        sub2.addView(imageView1[i]);
    }
    main.addView(sub1);
    main.addView(sub2);
```