# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first when changing fragment

Tags: navigation, fragment, drawer

Hi I have implemented the navigation drawer with Imageview but when i click on the listview to change the code it is giving me the above error can you please check my code below and let me know what is wrong in my code

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.RoundedBitmapDisplayer;

import kangaroo.com.begazad.Fragment.UserProfile;
import kangaroo.com.begazad.R;
import kangaroo.com.begazad.adapter.DrawerItemCustomAdapter;
import kangaroo.com.begazad.bean.ObjectDrawerItem;

/**
 * Created by user on 1/20/2016.
 */
public class SliderNavigation extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private String url ="http://img11.deviantart.net/0d86/i/2012/071/5/4/brad_pitt_png_by_sweetteens-d4sk57v.png";
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private RelativeLayout rl_Navigationdrawer;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    View headerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slidernavigationlayout);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        init();
        //Onclick();
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        rl_Navigationdrawer.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    public void init() {
        rl_Navigationdrawer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_Navigationdrawer);
        //  mNavigationDrawerItemTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        ObjectDrawerItem[] drawerItem = new ObjectDrawerItem[5];

        drawerItem[0] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.home, "Dashboard");
        drawerItem[1] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.friends, "Friends");
        drawerItem[2] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.groups, "Groups");
        drawerItem[3] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.message, "Messages");
        drawerItem[4] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.cart, "Shopping Cart");
        // drawerItem[5] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.mipmap.transaction, "Transaction");
        //  drawerItem[6] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.mipmap.inivtefriend, "Help");

        DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, drawerItem);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        headerView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.list_headerview,null);

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getApplicationContext()));

        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(1000)).cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.images)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.images)
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.images).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();


        ImageView imgview= ((ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.iv_navigation));


        imageLoader.displayImage(url, imgview, options);

        mDrawerList.addHeaderView(headerView);



        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.rl_Navigationdrawer:
                rl_Navigationdrawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                    }
                });
        }
    }


    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            selectItem(position);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }

    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        switch (position) {
            case 0:

                //     fragment = new Dashboard_Activity();
                System.out.println("Clicked"+mDrawerList.getItemAtPosition(position));
                fragment= new UserProfile();

                Toast.makeText(SliderNavigation.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //  fragment = new CreateFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                //fragment = new BookAppointment();

                Toast.makeText(SliderNavigation.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
//                    fragment = new UnderDevelopment();
                //  Toast.makeText(Dashboard_Activity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(SliderNavigation.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;


            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {

            System.out.println("IN IF");
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            // setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ..please referes these link...it might be helpful for you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301458/the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview-on-the-chil          And these also   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149981/fragments-the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview

Comment: Can you suggest any changes in the code

Comment: Only in case 0 , you want to open the fragment??...Not in other cases

Comment: Presently yes ...But i will have more fragment in future

Comment: Show you fragment class code.

Comment: check fragment class below

Comment: i guess in the onCreateView of your fragment, you have something like this, 
inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, container), if so then please put null instead of container