# Cannot add fragment dynamically

Tags: android

I’ve tried to add fragments dynamically but the app keeps stopping every time I switch to dynamically adding fragments rather than statically adding them.

```
package com.hiro.empty;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Logcat output:

```
2019-10-02 15:38:51.056 16022-16022/com.hiro.empty E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hiro.empty, PID: 16022
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5106)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4875)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4848)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:887)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        ...
```

MyFragment class

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, add a stacktrace from logcat with crash info.

Comment: @YuriiKyrylchuk I added the exception in the logcat output

Comment: Can you also add MyFragment code? Especially onCreateView() method

Comment: @YuriiKyrylchuk this is the entire class. I stripped everything else because I couldn’t figure out what was wrong with the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fragments - The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149981/fragments-the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-you-must-call-removeview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key thing is a third boolean parameter in `inflate` method. It will attach an inflated view to the parent. To fix an error you should change `onCreateView` method to this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Avoid passing null as a parent to have LayoutParams properly set.

Comment: I think that fixed the issue. Did’t notice that argument